# Download file by clicking a button in ReactJS

Tags: html, reactjs

I have a website built with ReactJS and there are some files (PDF,DOC etc) that I want to let visitors download.

But simple `href` tag doesn't start the download, instead refresh the page.

```html
<Button
          href="src/assets/files/exampleDoc.pdf"
          color="transparent"
          target="_blank"
          className={classes.navLink}
>
```

1. Why the `href` tag doesn't work in reactJS to download files?
2. How to download files with ReactJs using buttons?

Answer (score 17):

The following approach worked for me.

```
import ExampleDoc from '......src/assets/files/exampleDoc.pdf'

<a href={ExampleDoc} download="MyExampleDoc" target='_blank'>
   <Button className={classes.navLink}>My Example Doc</Button>
</a>
```

Answer (score 10):

If your file is on the frontend side and you are not storing it in backend you can do trigger the download by using the `<a>` tag in `HTML`. Try the following

```
<a href={require("../path/to/file.pdf")} download="myFile">Download file</a>
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: @Hadi Mir What if the file is stored in the backend?

Comment: Then I guess you can follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59287445/9920947. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
const DownloadButton = props => {
  const downloadFile = () => {
    window.location.href = "https://yoursite.com/src/assets/files/exampleDoc.pdf"
  }
  return (
            <button onClick={downloadFile} />
  )
}
export default DownloadButton;
```

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! Using `history` will navigate the page away actually to the path provided. This was great, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

for you first question you can check this it working

```
   <Button
      href="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxISEBUSEhAVFRUVFQ8VFRUVEA8VEBUPFRUWFhUVFRUYHSggGBolHRUVITEhJSkrLi4uFx8zODMtNygtLisBCgoKDg0OFxAQGi0eHx8tLS0tLS0tKy0vKy0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLy0tLS0tLSstLS0tLS0tLS0tKy0rLS0rLS0rK//AABEIALcBEwMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAbAAACAwEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAACAwABBAUGB//EADcQAAICAQIDBQYEBgIDAAAAAAABAhEDBCESMUFRYXGBkQUTFCKhsULB0fAyUmJy4fEGojOCkv/EABoBAAMBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAgMEBQb/xAApEQACAgICAgEEAAcAAAAAAAAAAQIRAyESMQQTQRQiUWEyUoGh4fDx/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD5nMUxkmKkdh5MQJC2HIFsRqgS6IEgGQtIlBIYmQoIECSFohaQxloKi0i6GIGg0ig0gEXFBxREg4oDRESCUQoxGRiAwVENQGQgHGIwsU4g8I+cQVEB2AomnToWoj8C3AjI9HRxR2KURuOPyhKBrejwPInTozS5mvSZDJlW4emdMhmM4XCzuQybC9RlpCFlMupz2ZxRx48LlKkIzTtmaQcpAUW2fRePgUIgNMhdFiOrieXkLkHJi2ZjQEgAmQDRFUWQsALRaKQQyWRlEZaACBwiCMxoYBLkVQxIFgAKDigUh0IgNIKMRsYlxgNjEBtgxiMjEtRGwgBLkVGI2MAoQHQgUYvJRmyRBUR+SJSgI0U9ClEfijuUoj8UQInk0bcS2GuOwOFDsipFTlR85lnc2c3JzJjdEZBWd0cfKCQx5BM5AtlMVnbg8eMCiFpF0B1FUQuiDA8gwJBSBZkWgCFlgUVRCyDERFkLARQSIkEhgUOxxAih8EAMlAMdJCpANFRRqxxE4VubcMAQN0XGI6MS4wGxiM5p5UgFEbGJSiacWKwRy5fJpAwgOjjNGLAaHg2LtI87J5Db7OTNblUMnHcnASzsXkUkgYodjiVDGa8OIXJIwy+Q2h+njsDq50hy2RztTltmHLlI48MHkmJBkyNlG1nv4oUiUQhAs3shCFjKIUWQAPGtglspEFELRVFgMjIQgCJRZC0hgXFBURIsLAKCNMEJxo040BMwMiFNDpi2gsqPQ3TR3OhigI0mM6OLHsP4OLPnq0BCA6OIdjxjlAiU6PMnltmeGI6Om04vHA6emiqM3kOTPldF4NMN1OKos14WjH7UzqqRPNtnBGUpTSOGsZfux6iFGA3kPQcwMWI0xjRNktzBqtd0RHJz6JhCeV1EPWajojA5AORDeMeKPb8fx1iQVlgl2VZ1pFosFFgUkWQhdDsZCBUQBniSEogiiEIWAEIQtIALSLSCoiAQUUWkWkHGIDRcYmnGtgIxNEYbCJkIkgFHc0SiBjjuDKukdHS4qjZstJIRllw44i8crYrs8OVzuTN8JjOMVGGxl1OWmZTV6Riocno62LcfHI0cnTamjbDUoyaaMMmJpm5ZpUL4G+Yh61CMvtHsElJmccUvhHQ4EuYnNrIx5HJzayT6ibNI4f5jrw+Hyf3s06jVuXgIKojN1SVI9TFjUFUUWiwUEkM6KLRaREgkhWUiJBJESCSCxlJBUWkEkFgVRAiBYHhSUXRKGWCFe1V279en78yUXQCKSGQiUkPhHYCXKgGiorcKQ3S47YEuVK2VwjcUBixbj8OEnkjKWekBDGaViNOn0jZq+D2J9iOWfmJaOVOAGKBtz4aMzQ+Vmq8jlEZrcv8ACuxF6LeRkyMbpM3C7F0jKUKx0ju5aUTkZd5Nh59daMvvTLGpds58OKUVbNWMemc74gv4hltMp4mzdKYiUxDyMpMpIqOMcmFYuIaHZ0QUUGmWikEhWbplpBFJlphZathJBJA8RfEBaiw0gkLsKxmigGSwLLGUsYdkBIBXrPArNLqi/ia5odwPrt40yp8S5tPvpcidiuL+Co54vr9GNhNPk0ZGr7K7UKlia7/UOTH64v5OrFDcjpUcvTZJLk77ndUbIZ0/4tn9B8rMZ4mmMSO/7L0D4HKjgYtTBNOT2vsZ7LF7TwR064cuNt9OON+a5nJ5ed44pRW2ed5zyRSUU9mWGh25GrDoTND2jKTpVR0NNxS6nFPNOKubo83K8kV92jfpdIqG5tOuFgYduo3UZVwczkflpS7PNk5cjiajEc/Pgo16rVJS5g59TFwu9z0ceWSo9PHzVHEzcxaZeSW4MWehZ6i6GMoFstByFQSRcUUi0xchMckQX70rjDYljkxyYUWIUi1IdHRDxvyaVIvjEKQSY6OmOJIdxBWKQaGbKCDTDQEUGkBaiEgkSKDSAqikgki0gkgsYNEGcJAsD5jHLKPKT9bNuLWqT4WvN+Bg25vfusG+wzTaKljjI68IQa4o+v8AslNPmvOjmafM4uuKr/pbVjMuXfmny/DRXIweF32dLwe/cVkhfQxaXNFN3t2XyNbyc7jyre+3tQ0zOUGmJenlzpMuOntcqH45cVtNoON1uOgeSS0ZtNlnjl8k2ufXp4dTr4v+RamFbxfb8n3pmBpPa9/AJx23ZjkwY8mpJMzyLHk/jin/AEOrD/lE3/Eq6fLuvqXl9up7e89VI4qxfvYqcY9TJeFhXUUjD6TBeo0dKetj/OvUKOW1zOPwLoXGLXJtG3q1ov6ePwzqyZcZI5scs+2/Gi3qnyr7oKY147Z0XkQPvTGtSu/0DjkT5MpIa8dLs0e8JxibLsqiljih3EWpCrCTGXSHJhxYlMZFgWh0WMiKixkQLQ2IyIER0UBSLihkUVFDYxFZSRIoNIuMTH7Q9q4sO0ncqvhirlX2XmIo20EkcDJ/yfHwS4YS4/wxlXC33tM5cvbuqkucYf2xS+rtgJtI9okWfOcmtyt377J5SnRBBZnWjfWUV5ip40qSfFz5WNx6xp/NFPv5P1NMdZHomr57Lb0FoTc18WYlKSTVOtr2+l9gvhZ0ZZcblvkW3bDYqWDE3fvKvomvzHQeyu1/Y5/A+g7HlcWmpX3fNVdm5oySUflgrp3+FpmZaWb/AAvz2FRSkn2aMmqVpwTXan9u804tVF3vXjRydwoSaaafmCk0TLDFo6OTOqbi3J9nTxFvUN7ySj57vyGvG5Q2a/uT4PWxOP5NsifdsqGzOKjX+2DHVb9nY/1NCnJrmn03rb9THqYw5r0TtfbYkI/K386rdPoTv4Zrxg1tG3S6hJ/Or8uoPxDt3SvlsmjM89reO7rq7ffyG4oca23++xLb7ZahH4QvPqJN9ldnIbhy7q+XPfqAo7NfvuJPHw/ddyfMV2VxSDlJN/Ld/Y0QafTyox7PrVdepfH2t7L1Gm0ROCa0b/evs+pfxC7PsYZt9H0fgKeSXNmnI5/SzpfFLlT9BmPOnyfl19DkSm3+q6mnHcluvMdiljpHUUxkchzcLklu/wDQWOc09pX3OKf1Kshd0dWEzRj8Dkx101zUPR/qFk9sSj+GPo3+YWWvwegxYGzRLTqMeKU4xS5t7JeZ5Re28zW0kv8A1Vox5dRPJvOTfY2/suhLNeSR28/t/esUL/qlaXkv1MWq9qZ5qnPgX9Hyv1u/qYFJ1tt39RUabrilfmwM+TZ0oe18qVe/fm4t+r3Odr87cuLaUpbt3bsdHSf1L0FZMUk6UfNVQMUZK+zMnPpz+ozilycb8ldG/HCuy/Ci6XmNRE8y/BmgoVyfoyGr3ZY+Jn7EcacXF01v6kxpt0lbZo+GVW5pvevm28e8bouCNy4raW+zpIzSOt5KjrZePQKvmu+6inoYxdyace9tP/Ix+0Yd/ojFqtRxO0q89qLfEyh7W96RpnqIqFY6T70uKu4we8vqRvtK27PqQ3Z0Qgol2iOLXNNWSNGqOeUlwLfp05dwUDbXRlxz6HRwaramlLss58sai2pc+1OwEw6FOCmdbVYMbjxRlGPltfpZjwKDdSk0u23TEtOioz7Btkxg1GrHZ5q+HiuP9K2/2VptQ4NOD59vaKkr3WwCRL2aRVHRefiXFKLtXyTppcwoS8Gn380ZdJkp05fK+e2z8TZm00Gri/Bq3y8BevWiZZuMqaE58e9xT36GeSY/SzVtOW+/NSG8SupOD59Oo1EHlp1RiizTjxykulLbpfgaJZIpXUfN1+RbzPZqFrtUkVxMZZW+kDpMa/lrx6mrhS/ewmWWXSHq0KcHJVNJ+DpFGV27ZolFAvGJx5ccNr4e5uw/iofzfR0NNEuMr0i3hb6/T8yvhE/9lx1EP516hcafKcf35hSFc1+ie4SWyRlzaSbd8QWfPTriT/tX3e4jJOXbL1f5pCbRrjjNbs0RxS6hQi+yvQx/EtbNu14Fy1ClzlJeFV9BWivXJm9MOMzLixTq4y4k+kkOx5t6lFx7/wAPqWmYSj+NjVIkvAPhK4SjO0BZA+Aggsye5hCO6W3VpW2c2eROXyxpdgep1Ll4dnYIRk3Z6OKDW5PYyMaAlzDjO1RTQi1+wZA2WuYaSfYIoWFxEcStt78gAkYt8hscTr98hcMjXIKOZ9QE7CjLaily3KyVzVotZlW6AVF8NFyihan38wgCiJGz2fKO8Xs+jTavu7DJZO8aJlHkqOpOD6OflGKfqZ1iy3081G/Mfo9VxJLql6mkukzjc5QdNGfFpefE7vp08Nx0FGOy27ugUlsYMkMi/Gq7duXePoSufbNaTbdu13Kmv1F5IpS/8lPsdPfwMkc87pTt9nTyYz4O3du+9OxXZfDi9sblTVLiTvq4/ejPknXVPw2Q5YsnSQvJhydil5R+gmVGvyiY5x2bf/a16MbGre8afck/VGKHOq8rr7h6i10i+9WvIVluG6Hww47q732+bc0xtcvmXe1Zy45K5wj9f2g56p38jY00KWKT/wAm3LOMueO//ltCp6bHfKUb8KNGJNreUW/7Rc8nNOVd9tL6oZlFtaRqxSiklxRfml9Bvgr9DEpQa3kn5K/p+hMS/kUq7nHh+5XIyeM1vJ/TL0v7FQyJ9GvFNEWSXVet/lYy33eo0ZtV/wBFScr2jfmQZb7PsQAv9HmuZRRDE9goNPYhBAVKikQgwCUXe/3Df8SaVLvdkIIQtLmFCiiDGNUu7oA4r92QgElSxdbLtpbkIJjRXEWns1+0yEAdBaXJwyT/AHXU7yiQhpA4vLXTL4RE1JbKEa8ef0IQpnLGVMyT0bVt1XOq28LW4yGqpbwddfmTLIQ9PR0xfsX3FRzRlb95Lfu/wUsi4qTTffFqyECzTglY3PwWlJfcHEsfJLv6/voQgzNR+3sd7u18rvrvfLxF5Fwq+Bd/L8yEKoxUnyoPHNtcWy7qELJFv5oxve+f2LISzWKVsv4Xs4fJNP1Bek4VtOS89iyA0R7JXRax5NuHLfiv8BvPOC+aKfen+RCDrVhF8pcWiL2lHsf0IQhHNnV9LjP/2Q=="
      color="transparent"
      target="_blank"
      download>Download
 </Button>
```

you can have a look hover here https://react.rocks/example/downloadbutton

```
function makeFile() {
  return {
   mime: 'text/plain',
   filename: 'myexportedfile.txt',
   contents: 'all of the exports',
  }
}


 <DownloadButton
   className='waves-effect waves-light btn' 
   genFile={makeFile}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

**I think, this will work perfectly fine:-**

```
<a href="assets/img/Rishabh-Singh-Resume.pdf" download="Rishabh's Resume" target='_blank'>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">Download Resume</button>
</a>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```html
<Button
          href="src/assets/files/exampleDoc.pdf"
          color="transparent"
          target="_blank"
          className={classes.navLink}
>
```